# why is Seq.iter and Seq.map so much slower?

Tags: performance, f#, seq

Consider this code in F#:

```
let n = 10000000
let arr = Array.init n (fun _ -> 0)

let rec buildList n acc i = if i = n then acc else buildList n (0::acc) (i + 1)
let lst = buildList n [] 0

let doNothing _ = ()
let incr x = x + 1

#time

arr |> Array.iter doNothing         // this takes 14ms
arr |> Seq.iter doNothing           // this takes 74ms

lst |> List.iter doNothing          // this takes 19ms
lst |> Seq.iter doNothing           // this takes 88ms

arr |> Array.map incr               // this takes 33ms
arr |> Seq.map incr |> Seq.toArray  // this takes 231ms!

lst |> List.map incr                // this takes 753ms
lst |> Seq.map incr |> Seq.toList   // this takes 2111ms!!!!
```

Why is the `iter` and `map` functions on the `Seq` module so much slower than the `Array` and `List` module equivalents?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you call in to `Seq` you lose the type information - moving to the next element in the list requires a call to `IEnumerator.MoveNext`.  Compare to for `Array` you just increment an index and for `List` you can just dereference a pointer.  Essentially, you are getting an extra function call for each element in the list.

The conversions back to `List` and `Array` also slow the code down for similar reasons

Comment: Though you are probably right about the actual cause. It doesn't really answer the question on a deeper level. Why did they choose to use MoveNext. As done through out the linq library you could start with a type check and in the case of a list or an array choose the matching version then difference for large sequences would then be neglect-able