# Why are some functions in the Seq module optimized whilst others were not in F#?

Tags: performance, collections, f#

This is a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874557/why-is-seq-iter-and-seq-map-so-much-slower) regarding the `Seq` module's `iter` and `map` functions being much slower compared to the `Array` and `List` module equivalents.

Looking at the source, I can see that some functions such as `isEmpty` and `length` performs a very simple type check to optimize for arrays and lists before resorting to using `IEnumerator`.

```
[<CompiledName("IsEmpty")>]
let isEmpty (source : seq<'T>)  = 
    checkNonNull "source" source
    match source with 
    | :? ('T[]) as a -> a.Length = 0
    | :? list<'T> as a -> a.IsEmpty
    | :? ICollection<'T> as a -> a.Count = 0
    | _ -> 
        use ie = source.GetEnumerator()
        not (ie.MoveNext())

[<CompiledName("Length")>]
let length (source : seq<'T>)    = 
    checkNonNull "source" source
    match source with 
    | :? ('T[]) as a -> a.Length
    | :? ('T list) as a -> a.Length
    | :? ICollection<'T> as a -> a.Count
    | _ -> 
        use e = source.GetEnumerator() 
        let mutable state = 0 
        while e.MoveNext() do
            state <-  state + 1;
        state
```

In the case of the `iter` the same approach can be done to vastly improve its performance, when I [shadowed](https://gist.github.com/2869351) the `iter` function it presented significant gains over the built-in version:

```
[<CompiledName("Iterate")>]
let iter f (source : seq<'T>) = 
    checkNonNull "source" source
    use e = source.GetEnumerator()
    while e.MoveNext() do
        f e.Current;
```

My question is, given that some of the functions in the `Seq` module were optimized for use with specific collection types (arrays, list< T>, etc.) how come other functions such as `iter` and `nth` were not optimized in a similar way?

Also, in the case of `map` function, as @mausch pointed out, is it not possible to employ a similar approach to `Enumerable.Select` (see below) and build up specialized iterators for different collection types?

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
      if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
      if (selector == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("selector");
      if (source is Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>)
        return ((Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>) source).Select<TResult>(selector);
      if (source is TSource[])
        return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult>((TSource[]) source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
      if (source is List<TSource>)
        return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>((List<TSource>) source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
      else
        return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
    }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get a decent answer to a 'why' question like this here; my best _guess_ is simply lack of developer time.

Answer (score 4):

> In the case of the iter the same approach can be done to vastly improve its performance

I think this is where the answer to your question is. Your test is artificial, and doesn't actually test any real world examples of these methods. You tested 10,000,000 iterations of these methods in order to get differences in timing in `ms`.

Converted back to per item costs, here they are:

```
          Array   List
Seq.iter   4 ns    7 ns
Seq.map   20 ns   91 ns
```

These methods are typically used once per collection, meaning this cost is an additional linear factor to your algorithms performance. In the worst case you are losing less than `100 ns` per item in a list (which you shouldn't be using if you care about performance that much).

Contrast this with the case of `length` which is always linear in the general case. By adding this optimization you provide enormous benefit to someone who forgot to manually cache the length but luckily is always given a list.

Similarly you may call `isEmpty` many times, and adding another object creation is silly if you can just ask directly. (This one isn't as strong an argument)

Another thing to keep in mind is that neither of those methods actually looks at more than one element of the output. What would you expect the following code to do (excluding syntax errors or missing methods)

```
type Custom() =
  interface IEnumerable with
    member x.GetEnumerator() =
      return seq {
        yield 1
        yield 2
      }
  interface IList with
    member x.Item with
      get(index) = index
    member x.Count = 12

 let a = Custom()
 a |> Seq.iter (v -> printfn (v.ToString()))
```

Comment: Your example demonstrates why I consider this a misfeature. It follows the principle of least surprise that `Seq` only depends on `seq<_>`, `Array` on arrays, and `List` on `list<_>`. It's up to the programmer to choose which interface should be used.

Comment: @Daniel: It is an implementation detail to improve performance. BTW, the F# implementation doesn't depend on `IList`, only on `list`, which can't be overloaded to create these weird situations.

Comment: No, but you could contrive something similar using `ICollection<_>` and `seq<_>`.

Comment: @Daniel: But that behavior wouldn't be surprising, since you are actually saying "what is the count of this sequence object", not "how many items are in the enumeration of this sequence object", I would consider the fact that the enumerable is fully enumerated is an implementation detail.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect the two to be the same? The possibility that they could differ seems bizarre. But this is getting off point. If a method accepts a value of type `'T`, I expect it to interact with it only as a `'T`, not repeatedly downcast, fishing for a more concrete type to use. It would be a tenable approach, given that let-bound functions can't be overloaded, if more precisely typed versions didn't exist.

Comment: @Daniel: It is an implementation detail that can provide significant performance enhancements, and only becomes a problem when you break well defined standards. I can't possibly find a way to justify removing it other than from a purity standpoint. When righting software changing an implementation detail purely for purity reasons is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you (and will rest my case here :-)). My point is the question assumes this kind of optimization is generally desirable. While it may be occasionally worthwhile it hardly seems like a pattern that should be broadly applied.

Comment: @Daniel: My apologies, I always get side tracked in these comment threads. You are correct that generally it is best to be careful with such things. The broad reaching changes that OP asked for are too much.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, the type-checks in `Seq.length`/`isEmpty` seem like mistakes. I assume most `Seq` functions don't perform such checks for orthogonality: type-specific versions already exist in the `List`/`Array` modules. Why duplicate them?

Those checks make more sense in LINQ since it only uses `IEnumerable` directly.

Comment: At least in the case of `Seq.length`, the optimization can potentially turn an O(n) operation into an O(1) operation.  I doubt this is a mistake.

Comment: @kvb: That merely emphasizes the OP's point. Can you answer his question? If you think those are valid optimizations (in spite of available type-specific alternatives) why not apply them to other functions? They seem unnecessary and redundant to me.

Comment: No, I don't know the answer, but in the case of `Seq.iter`, `Seq.map`, etc. doing a type test wouldn't change the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm, just the constant factors.

Comment: It depends on what kind of input you are expecting. If you are taking in a `seq` from an external source (say a library) then you would want those enhancements, for the same reason that LINQ does.

Comment: @kvb: My contention isn't that these are bad optimizations. I'm merely arguing that their presence in `isEmpty`/`length` is less consistent and warrants more justification than their absence from other functions.