# Seq.iter slower than native mapping : any generic solution?

Tags: generics, compiler-construction, f#, inline, functor

The issue has already shown up before, and its reason answered by John Palmer :
[why is Seq.iter and Seq.map so much slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874557/why-is-seq-iter-and-seq-map-so-much-slower)

```
let ar = Array.zeroCreate<int> (64*1024*1024)
#time
//Real: 00:00:00.171, CPU: 00:00:00.171, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
for i in 0 .. ar.Length - 1 do
    ar.[i] <- ar.[i]*3

//Real: 00:00:00.327, CPU: 00:00:00.328, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
ar |> Array.iteri(fun i _ -> ar.[i] <- ar.[i]*3)

//Real: 00:00:02.249, CPU: 00:00:02.250, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
ar |> Seq.iteri(fun i _ -> ar.[i] <- ar.[i]*3)
```

I wonder if there are some kind of "inlining" or other generic mechanisms that could map, say a Sequence to (its last known?) concrete type to accelerate those behaviour. 
For instance here i have static guarantee that I will iterate over an array.

Do you know of satisfactory solution that exists in theory to this ? (what would be there fancy name ?)

Are there some langage that acknowledge and solve that issue nicely ?

Comment: You can do this using higher-kinded generics, which F# doesn't support. Haskell and Scala both do, and the type would be something like `Iterable c => c a -> (a -> ()) -> ()` and you could then provide implementations for `Array`, `Seq` and any other collection type. You might find http://adriaanm.github.com/files/higher.pdf of interest.

Comment: What are you trying to do, make generic `map` and `iter` functions that are optimal for all collections? My guess is if that were possible F# wouldn't have separate modules such as `Array`, `List`, and `Seq`.

Comment: The compiler actually does make some of these optimisations - check the implementation of `Seq.Length` at https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs line 1027.  Although it doesn't bother for `map/iter` type functions

Comment: "You can do this using higher-kinded generics, which F# doesn't support. Haskell and Scala both do". This comment does not make sense. The question asks about the performance of something done in F#. So you obviously can do this in F# without higher-kinded generics. Futhermore, Haskell is notoriously unpredictably slow in this context, turning fast arithmetic operations into slow virtual dispatch precisely because of this language feature leading to perf bugs like this one: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2271

Comment: JonHarrop, Lee thank you for your comment. I think they both make sense, with different viewpoint. @JohnPalmer, thanks for the informative link, I find myself not looking enough at the source, unlike in ruby, where it is much easier to get access to it from the eval environment....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that you don't have Higher Kinded Types in F# but still you can use inline functions and emulate some Typeclass behaviour.
By defining a Functor you have a generic solution to native mapping:

```
type Fmap = Fmap with
    static member ($) (_Functor:Fmap, x:List<_> ) = fun f -> List.map    f x  
    static member ($) (_Functor:Fmap, x:array<_>) = fun f -> Array.map   f x
    static member ($) (_Functor:Fmap, x:_ [,]   ) = fun f -> Array2D.map f x
    static member ($) (_Functor:Fmap, x:_ [,,]  ) = fun f -> Array3D.map f x
    static member ($) (_Functor:Fmap, x:_ [,,,] ) = fun f ->
        Array4D.init (x.GetLength 0) (x.GetLength 1) (x.GetLength 2) (x.GetLength 3) (fun a b c d -> f x.[a,b,c,d])

let inline fmap f x = (Fmap $ x) f
```

Take for instance fmap, this function is inline and it will accept any type defined in the overloads and it will execute as fast as calling the function directly (which is what actually happens behind the scenes).
To iter you can use fmap and discard the result, in your case you may want to define something like fmapi to have an index available.

Keep in mind you should call these functions always with the the concrete type, if you pass a Seq<'a> it will fail, you should not mix both approaches: subtype and ad-hoc polymorphism.

Comment: So this is the answer, both theorically, higher kind types, and pratically, with the added f# code. however, I guess Jon has a point as well, of higher concern.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you know of satisfactory solution that exists in theory to this ? (what would be there fancy name ?)

You cannot have your cake and eat it.

> Are there some langage that acknowledge and solve that issue nicely ?

F# acknowledged this issue and solved it nicely. You can either have a clear performance profile and fast compilation like F# or you can have an unpredictable performance profile and slow compilation due to a massively complex compiler laden with optimization passes for special cases like this. F# chose the former (pragmatic) solution.

Comment: you have a very good point regarding a more general question.if I could mark 2 answers, I would mark this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

For `iter` you could check the type of the collection and dispatch to an optimal implementation. Where you run into problems is with `map`, which needs to return `T<'b>` for some `T<'a>`. This requires higher kinded types, which F# does not directly support. Here's an attempt at `map` that illustrates the problem:

```
module AnySeq =
  let map<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd when 'a :> seq<'b> and 'd :> seq<'c>> (f: 'b -> 'c) (s: 'a) : 'd =
    let (!) x = unbox (box x)
    let tyDef = s.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    if tyDef = typedefof<list<_>> then !(List.map f !s)
    elif tyDef = typedefof<array<_>> then !(Array.map f !s)
    else !(Seq.map f !s)
```

If you try to use it to convert an `int list` to `float list`:

```
let ints = List.init 10000000 id
let floats = ints |> AnySeq.map float
```

you get a value restriction error:

> The value 'floats' has been inferred to have generic type val floats : '_a when '_a :> seq

It works if you add a type annotation to `floats`, but then you haven't accomplished anything.